# what is the exact path name to a folder inside assets file? (android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shapefile

I have a couple ShapeFiles saved inside of it's own "shapeFiles" folder under the assets folder in my android project (using eclipse). I'm trying to access these files, but I just can't seem to get the right path...

I'm guessing cause It's running on my android device, the path won't be the same maybe?

I've tried multiple types of paths like:

```
File path = new File("/assets/shapeFiles/");
File path = new File("/shapeFiles/");
File path = new File("/projectName/assets/shapeFiles/");
```

Always getting the same "no such file or directory"

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access Assets folder directly, first you need to copy the data from assets folder to android and then only you can access the files inside the folder.

Comment: Nothing is true of what you said. Think about it. If you copy the files you access them directly. There is no need for a copy to the file system if you only want to read their content.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to access these files, but I just can't seem to get the right path.

They are not files on the device. They are files on your development machine. They are entries in the APK file on the device.

To access assets, use an `AssetManager`, obtained by calling `getAssets()` on any `Context`, such as an `Activity`.